# Is there any way I can output the variable name instead of the value? [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays

for example, I have a list of integer variables

```
int CLUTCH_CASE = 8;
int CS20 = 6;
int DANGER_ZONE_CASE = 6;
int TOTAL_CASE = 0;
```

I have an array:

```
int CaseValue[] = {CS20, CLUTCH_CASE, DANGER_ZONE_CASE};
```

and I output the value of total cases, which is going to be:

```
for (int counter=0;counter<CaseValue.length;counter++) {
    TOTAL_CASE += CaseValue[counter];
}
System.out.println("You have "+CaseValue.length+" CSGO Cases");
System.out.println("You have a total of "+TOTAL_CASE+" CSGO Cases:");
```

Output:

```
You have 3 CSGO Cases
You have a total of 20 CSGO Cases:
```

yet I also want to output the name.

Example:
(CASENAME are just placeholders for this example. I wanted to use CaseValue[].NAME even that does not exist since it's an example)

```
for (int counter2=0;counter2<CaseValue.length;counter2++) {
    System.out.println(CASENAME+": "+CaseValue[counter2]);
}
```

My expected and wanted output to be:

```
CLUTCH_CASE: 8
CS20: 6
DANGER_ZONE_CASE: 6
```

Is there any way to output the name of the integer variable?

Answer (score 2):

There is no command in Java to access the variable name.

You could use a map (like stated in other answers), but I'd also like to present a simple possibility that is possible without advanced features of Java.

What you could do is the following:

```
String[] caseName = {"CS20", "CLUTCH_CASE", "DANGER_ZONE_CASE"};
```

After that you can do:

```
for (int i=0; i<CaseValue.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(caseName[i] + ": " + CaseValue[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map.

```
Map<String, Integer> ma = new Hashmap()
for (int counter=0;counter<CaseValue.length;counter++) {
    TOTAL_CASE += CaseValue[counter];
    ma.put(<your_key>, <your_value>)
}
```

I still dont understand your code completely. So cannot give you a full working snippet. I have however added a snippet on how you could possibly use a map. Store the key as the name that you want and its corresponding value in that key of the map.

Comment: Better use a LinkedHashMap, to preserve the ordering.

Comment: For some reason, all the answers with hashmap as a solution got downvoted. May I knwo why?

Comment: Because they don't preserve the order of the output.

Comment: Was that a requirement?? As far as I can see he's juzt printing.

Comment: Yes, it was a requirement. Not explicitly written down, but all the example output was in declaration order.

Comment: The title clearly says on hwo to show the variable name. It has nothing to do with order. The example output is not in declaration order. `CS20` is declared first in the array but printed second.

Comment: There could be a hundred things not explicit in the question. We can't address them all. Point them out.. yes. But that's all we can do.

Comment: For the asked question hashmap is in no way a wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use java.lang.Class and its getFields() method to return an array of java.lang.reflect Field[] class object
Below will give you an idea of how, go take a look in the API docs for a better more suitable set of methods to design the process with a List or Set to use contains() method so you can put it in a class and call when you want in a program.

```
import java.lang.Class;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

Field[] varFset = ((java.lang.Class)this).getFields();
// compare names processing code over the array here
String varname = varFset[x].getName();
```

Comment: This is not a case for using reflections at all. Please don't use reflections for such basic tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a HashMap.

```java
enum CaseType {
   CLUTCH_CASE,
   CS20,
   DANGER_ZONE_CASE;
}
Map<CaseType, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(3);
map.put(CaseType.CLUTCH_CASE, 8);
map.put(CaseType.CS20, 6);
map.put(CaseType.DANGER_ZONE_CASE, 6);
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key.name() + ": " + value));
```

Comment: Better use a LinkedHashMap, to preserve the ordering.